# Mutliple condition IIF Statement expression expected

Tags: visual-studio

I have had a number of challenges trying to get this multiple argument IIF statement to work.  Looking for help on the parenthesis placment.

This errors out with the "contains an error bc30201 expression expected"

`=IIF((Fields!SSFLAG.Value) ='W', "Aqua"), IIF((Fields!SSFLAG.Value) ='X', "LightGrey")), IIF(((Fields!SSFLAG.Value) ='Y', "Khaki"))), IIF((((Fields!SSFLAG.Value) ='Z', "Pink","Plum")))))`

I have had success with multiple IIF arguments with numerical values however this one is just not working for me.

Comment: What version of SSRS are you using?

Comment: Visual Studio 2017

Comment: SSRS is not VS. What is your SSRS version?

Comment: I guess that might be a misstatement then in my question. This is a textbox expression in Visial Studio

Comment: Your expression has unbalanced parens `(` `)` and is missing parameters (`IIF` has 3 parameters, but your code only uses 2 in some places).

Answer (score 0):

In SSRS, [the `IIF` function behaves the same as in Visual Basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/iif-function), such that it requires **three** parameter arguments: the test expression, when-true, and when-false, but your posted expression is invalid.

If we take the code you've posted, but format it for readability, the problem becomes more apparent:

```
=IIF(
    (Fields!SSFLAG.Value) ='W',
    "Aqua"
),
IIF(
    (Fields!SSFLAG.Value) = 'X',
    "LightGrey"
) 
),
IIF(
    (
        (Fields!SSFLAG.Value) = 'Y',
        "Khaki"
    )
)
),
IIF(
    (
        (
            (Fields!SSFLAG.Value) ='Z', "Pink","Plum")
        )
    )
))
```

In the above code, observe that:

1. The first `IIF` only has 2 arguments provided, instead of 3.
2. The first `IIF` is followed by a `,` then another `IIF`, which is syntactically invalid.
3. The third `IIF` has `(` and `)` around 2 parameters (which is not a valid expression for the first argument of `IIF` and no second or third argument at all.
4. Ditto for the fourth `IIF`: the extra parens break your expression entirely.
5. Also, SSRS uses double-quotes `"` for string-literals, not single-quotes: `'`, so `'W'` should be `"W"`.

I suspect that you actually want *this*:

```
=IIF(
    Fields!SSFLAG.Value = "W",
    "Aqua",
    IIF(
        Fields!SSFLAG.Value = "X",
        "LightGrey",
        IIF(
            Fields!SSFLAG.Value = "Y",
            "Khaki",
            IIF(
                Fields!SSFLAG.Value = "Z",
                "Pink",
                "Plum"
            )
        )
    )
)
```

...which flattens down to:

```
=IIF( Fields!SSFLAG.Value) = "W", "Aqua", IIF( Fields!SSFLAG.Value = "X", "LightGrey", IIF( Fields!SSFLAG.Value = "Y", "Khaki", IIF(               Fields!SSFLAG.Value = "Z", "Pink", "Plum" ) ) ) )
```

That said, as your expression only checks `Fields!SSFlag.Value` repeatedly, [you should use `SWITCH` instead](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6973/ssrs-iif-switch-choose-functions/), as that's more readable:

```
=SWITCH(
    Fields!SSFLAG.Value = "W", "Aqua",
    Fields!SSFLAG.Value = "X", "LightGrey",
    Fields!SSFLAG.Value = "Y", "Khaki",
    Fields!SSFLAG.Value = "Z", "Pink",
    1=1                      , "Plum"
)
```

...which flattens to:

```
=SWITCH( Fields!SSFLAG.Value = "W", "Aqua", Fields!SSFLAG.Value = "X", "LightGrey", Fields!SSFLAG.Value = "Y", "Khaki", Fields!SSFLAG.Value = "Z", "Pink", 1=1, "Plum" )
```

Comment: Thank you for the two examples, the =Switch makes sense also.  When I put either of these in I get the following ... Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error  [rsCompilerErrorInExpression] The BackgroundColor expression for the text box ‘SSFLAG’ contains an error: [BC30201] Expression expected

Comment: That error message sounds like you still have syntax errors somewhere. I suggest you clear the expression entirely first, ensure there'sn no errors - then proceed to use a _single_ `IIF` with literal string arguments, then incrementally replace the last argument with the next nested `IIF` expression. I can't really help you beyond that without access to your project.

Comment: I figured it out.   Each letter value needed to be in quotes. =SWITCH(
    Fields!SSFLAG.Value = "W", "Aqua",
    Fields!SSFLAG.Value = "X", "LightGrey",
    Fields!SSFLAG.Value = "Y", "Khaki",
    Fields!SSFLAG.Value = "Z", "Pink",
    1=1                      , "Plum")